# Improving layout of generated ASP.Net MVC form views

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc

Are there examples on how to quickly improve the layout of generated ASP.Net MVC form views? I'd like to improve the look of my ASP.Net MVC forms for an LOB CRUD application, but don't want to spend a lot of time working on CSS layouting.

Comment: I don't mean NO css. I'd like to have minimal / simple / elegant CSS, something that can be added to the header and applied to all the generated forms en-masse.

Comment: A more specific question related to this need is posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990185/how-do-i-implement-column-style-on-pre-existing-elements-in-a-generated-asp-net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of something close to what I'm looking for.

```
<style type="text/css">
form
{
    background-color: #f3f3f3;
    border: solid 1px #a1a1a1;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 300px;
}

.editor-label, .editor-field
{
    display: block;
    width: 120px;
    float: left;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.editor-label
{
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 20px;
}

br
{
    clear: left;
}
</style>
```

Comment: You are on the right track then. You can use CSS type selectors to format all HTML elements of a given type (like you did in form) or class selectors to match elements with a given class (like you did in .editor-label). Not sure what else you are looking for, though.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for tips on how to improve this further. For instance, is there a way to use the same technique to make the fields appear in several columns without touching their markup (hundreds across many forms!) in the app?

Comment: Is it ok if I delete this question and replace one that's more specific about CSS and layouting?

Comment: Here's the new question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7990185/how-do-i-implement-column-style-on-pre-existing-elements-in-a-generated-asp-net